# SQLBase, query multiple values from one table column

Tags: left-join, multiple-value, sqlbase

I have big problem with SQLBase database, or it's engine.
I have history with MySQL but not with SQLBase.

I have:

1. Multiple tables joined together,
2. work order that has,
3. multiple values in a column and
4. I want them on query result in a row.

For example, this is what I want:

```
table
ordernr|type|..............|productnr
-------------------------------------
1141356| v1 | .............|fe465
1141356| v2 | .............|hty546
1141356| v3 | .............|rgrg211
1454446| v1 | .............|dw885
1454446| v2 | .............|fee885
1454446| v3 | .............|wwf6664
1231231| v1 | .............|ff664
1591591| v1 | .............|gg123
1591591| v2 | .............|jj5891

query result
ordernr | .............|  v1 |  v2  |  v3
--------------------------------------------
1141356 | ............ |fe465|hty546|rgrg211  
1454446 | ............ |dw885|fee885|wwf6664
1231231 | ............ |ff664|  -   |   -
1591591 | ............ |gg123|jj5891|   -
```

But when I am trying it I get only orders with one or two or three values.
Depending how I write on the query,
but I want all values showing.
I tried using left join but no result.

Only ordernr comes from other table.

Please, ask if you need more information.
I try my best to help.

EDIT:
**Hi! It works! Somehow my query started working as it should. But let me say that I have worked with MySQL over 10 years without any bigger hassle, but this SQLBase is giving me high blood pressure. :)**

Comment: Now I have each v1, v2, v3 value on their own rows with ordernr.
How I get this to single row?
WHERE ordernr=1141356 AND (type='v1' or type='v2' or type='v3')

Comment: Read about "pivoting". If you clearly expressed what you wanted in a sentence & googled it you would get hits.

Comment: I read about pivoting. But SQLBase didn't work with it, and I tried it multiple ways, but no desired result. I had to read SQLBase Language Reference multiple times until I managed to get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing the schema , have you tried Group By  i.e.  Group By ordernr , to give all on one row.